# custom Javascript sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

[image]

I need to sort this array of strings like in column 1.
Not sure how to tackle this with sort's compare function.

Edit:
Some more info, it should be alphabetical, but grouped.
So first the non 45 en 90 strings then the 45 and then the 90's.

Some background info:
These are parts numbers for hydraulic fittings. The 45 and 90 are degrees.

Any help welcome!

Comment: what's the rule for sorting? - just ignore the 2nd and 3rd characters?

Comment: what is the proposed order? please add the data in text form.

Comment: Can you express the sorting rule *in English*…?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let items = ['X06BJF06', 'X06BJF45S06', 'X06BJF90S06', 'X08BJF08', 'X08BJF45S08', 'X08BJF90S08']

items.sort((a,b) => a.replace(/^(.)\d+(.*)$/, '$1$2').localeCompare(b.replace(/^(.)\d+(.*)$/, '$1$2')));

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X! Simple and effective!